# C# Missing character on encrypt decrypt

Tags: c#, encryption

I tried to create encrypt decrypt function on my C# project

But somehow it got issue when the text need to be encrypted is more than 16 characters

The decrypted text is missing characters at the end

If I use shorter plainText like "abcde" it can decrypt the text with no problem

But if the plainText is long like on the example, some of the last character is gone

Need your help to check this code

Thanks

*program.cs*

```
string plainText = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwhyz1234567890";
string password = Convert.ToBase64String(Cryptography.GenerateRandomEntropy());
string encryptedText = Cryptography.Encrypt(plainText, password);
string decryptedText = Cryptography.Decrypt(encryptedText, password);

Console.WriteLine("Text: " + plainText); //abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwhyz1234567890
Console.WriteLine("Pass: " + password);
Console.WriteLine("Enc:  " + encryptedText);
Console.WriteLine("Dec:  " + decryptedText); //abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwhyz123456
```

*crypt.cs*

```
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public static class Cryptography
{
    private const int Keysize = 128;

    private const int DerivationIterations = 1000;

    public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
    {
        var saltStringBytes = GenerateRandomEntropy();
        var ivStringBytes = GenerateRandomEntropy();
        var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        using (var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations))
        {
            var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(Keysize / 8);
            using (var symmetricKey = Aes.Create())
            {
                symmetricKey.BlockSize = Keysize;
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                using (var key = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes))
                {
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, key, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes);
                            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                            var cryptTextBytes = saltStringBytes;
                            cryptTextBytes = cryptTextBytes.Concat(ivStringBytes).ToArray();
                            cryptTextBytes = cryptTextBytes.Concat(memoryStream.ToArray()).ToArray();
                            memoryStream.Close();
                            cryptoStream.Close();
                            return Convert.ToBase64String(cryptTextBytes);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string cryptText, string passPhrase)
    {
        var cryptTextBytesWithSaltAndIv = Convert.FromBase64String(cryptText);
        var saltStringBytes = cryptTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Take(Keysize / 8).ToArray();
        var ivStringBytes = cryptTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Skip(Keysize / 8).Take(Keysize / 8).ToArray();
        var cryptTextBytes = cryptTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Skip((Keysize / 8) * 2).Take(cryptTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Length - ((Keysize / 8) * 2)).ToArray();

        using (var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations))
        {
            var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(Keysize / 8);
            using (var symmetricKey = Aes.Create())
            {
                symmetricKey.BlockSize = Keysize;
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                using (var key = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes))
                {
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cryptTextBytes))
                    {
                        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, key, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            var plainTextBytes = new byte[cryptTextBytes.Length];
                            cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes);
                            memoryStream.Close();
                            cryptoStream.Close();
                            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static byte[] GenerateRandomEntropy()
    {
        var randomBytes = new byte[Keysize / 8];
        using (var rngCsp = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            rngCsp.GetBytes(randomBytes);
        }
        return randomBytes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are applying a padding on both the encrypt and decrypt, so on decrypt it will also apply that padding to remove the last 8 bytes and in your case some actual data. You can see this more visual with zero padding. You can try something like this to better suite you.

*crypt.cs*

```
private const int Keysize = 128;

private const int DerivationIterations = 1000;

public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
{
    var saltStringBytes = GenerateRandomEntropy();
    var ivStringBytes = GenerateRandomEntropy();
    var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

    using (var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations))
    {
        var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(Keysize / 8);
        using (var symmetricKey = Aes.Create())
        {
            symmetricKey.BlockSize = Keysize;
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            using (var key = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes))
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, key, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes);
                        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                        var cryptTextBytes = saltStringBytes;
                        cryptTextBytes = cryptTextBytes.Concat(ivStringBytes).ToArray();
                        cryptTextBytes = cryptTextBytes.Concat(memoryStream.ToArray()).ToArray();
                        memoryStream.Close();
                        cryptoStream.Close();
                        return Convert.ToBase64String(cryptTextBytes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static string Decrypt(string cryptText, string passPhrase)
{
    var cryptTextBytesWithSaltAndIv = Convert.FromBase64String(cryptText);
    var saltStringBytes = cryptTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Take(Keysize / 8).ToArray();
    var ivStringBytes = cryptTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Skip(Keysize / 8).Take(Keysize / 8).ToArray();
    var cryptTextBytes = cryptTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Skip((Keysize / 8) * 2).Take(cryptTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Length - ((Keysize / 8) * 2)).ToArray();

    using (var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations))
    {
        var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(Keysize / 8);
        using (var symmetricKey = Aes.Create())
        {
            symmetricKey.BlockSize = Keysize;
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            using (var key = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes))
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cryptTextBytes))
                {
                    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, key, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        var plainTextBytes = new byte[cryptTextBytes.Length];
                        
                        cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes);

                        memoryStream.Close();
                        cryptoStream.Close();
                        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes).TrimEnd('\0');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static byte[] GenerateRandomEntropy()
{
    var randomBytes = new byte[Keysize / 8];
    using (var rngCsp = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        rngCsp.GetBytes(randomBytes);
    }
    return randomBytes;
}
```

*output*

```
Text: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwhyz1234567890
Pass: 4UnD6QCMCe0vgYA0ZHJKaw==
Enc:  SdKNaXWweKyaJsh93bvPeMzmtewNHlKdN3LTeWZEWD2ubQOY88d+bbetB+4ymGguYYBZG54NEGCu+9Epg4+1dW+8kdNKJ2Sf71HIVoaFxnc=
Dec:  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwhyz1234567890
```

Comment: You can of course remove the trim to see the zeros to understand more what I mean about the padding.